# Código funcional en versión denebeans java 8 no funciona en netbeans java 6

Tags: java, java-8, sftp, jsch, java-6

Buenas por favor creen que me puedan ayudar, tengo un código funcional en versión 8 de java pero lo paso a versión 6 no me funciona. 
Me pueden ayudar por favor. adjuntare el código.
Actualmente no me acepta  la parte de los cath. Me los marca en error[image: Error java]

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Descargar {


static final String USERNAME = "SFTP";
static String HOST = "200.200.222.7";
static int PORT = 55507;
static String PASSWORD = "patitossecreto";
static String REMOTEPATH ="";/*Agregar el working file para la descarga*/
static String LOCALPATH="";/*Agregar el working file para la descarga*/
static String FILE="";/*Archivo que deseamos descargar*/

public static void Descargar(String pUser, String pPass,String pHost, int pPort, String localpath, String remotepath, String file)
        throws Exception {
    JSch sftp = new JSch();
    // Instancio el objeto session para la transferencia
    Session session = null;
    // instancio el canal sftp
    ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;
    try {
        // Inciciamos el JSch con el usuario, host y puerto
        session = sftp.getSession(pUser, pHost, pPort);
        // Seteamos el password
        session.setPassword(pPass);
        // El SFTP requiere un intercambio de claves
        // con esta propiedad le decimos que acepte la clave
        // sin pedir confirmación
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(prop); 
        session.connect();

        // Abrimos el canal de sftp y conectamos
        channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
        channelSftp.connect();

        // Convertimos el archivo a transferir en un OutputStream donde se va a guardar
        OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                localpath+'/'+file));
        // Iniciamos la transferencia
        channelSftp.get(remotepath+'/'+file, os);
    } catch (JSchException | SftpException | FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new Exception(e);
    } finally {
        // Cerramos el canal y session
        if (channelSftp.isConnected())
            channelSftp.disconnect();
        if (session.isConnected())
            session.disconnect();
    }// end try
}// end Descargar

    public static void ListaDoc(String pUser, String pPass,String pHost, int pPort, String remotepath)
        throws Exception {
    JSch sftp = new JSch();
    // Instancio el objeto session para la transferencia
    Session session = null;
    // instancio el canal sftp
    ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;
    try {
        // Inciciamos el JSch con el usuario, host y puerto
        session = sftp.getSession(pUser, pHost, pPort);
        // Seteamos el password
        session.setPassword(pPass);
        // El SFTP requiere un intercambio de claves
        // con esta propiedad le decimos que acepte la clave
        // sin pedir confirmación
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(prop); 
        session.connect();

        // Abrimos el canal de sftp y conectamos
        channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
        channelSftp.connect();

                    channelSftp.ls(remotepath);

    } catch (JSchException | SftpException e) {
        throw new Exception(e);
    } finally {
        // Cerramos el canal y session
        if (channelSftp.isConnected())
            channelSftp.disconnect();
        if (session.isConnected())
            session.disconnect();
    }// end try
}// end ListaDoc

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
                    ListaDoc(USERNAME,PASSWORD, HOST, PORT, REMOTEPATH);
        Descargar(USERNAME, PASSWORD, HOST, PORT, LOCALPATH, REMOTEPATH,FILE);
} // End main

} // End Class Descargar
```

Comment: ¿Y qué error te da? Siempre que preguntes indicar el tipo de error facilitará que tengas una respuesta más rápida y precisa. Por favor [edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/103187/edit) colocando en su contenido el mensaje de error que te arroja el programa.

Comment: eso para por las versiones que manejas al momento de pasar a una versión menor es posible que no funciones pero al revés si de pasar a una versión mayor ejemplo de netbeans 6 a la 8 , lo que te recomiendo es crear un proyecto en la versión 6 y copiar el código

Comment: Hola Esteban gracias por el comentario, realmente eso aplique cree un proyecto en jdk 6 y pase poco a poco el código y aún asi no funciona.

Comment: que tipo de error te aparece o te indica neatbens  al momento de realizar la compilación del programa

Comment: no muestra error. lo compila sin problema pero las marcar rojas siguen.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que está pasando allí es una característica que se agregó desde Java 7 llamada [multicatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html).

En versiones anteriores de Java se ponían varios catch, uno por cada tipo de excepción

```
catch (IOException ex) {
     logger.log(ex);
     throw ex;
} catch (SQLException ex) {
     logger.log(ex);
     throw ex;
}
```

Algo que se dieron cuenta es que muchas veces el código era exactamente el mismo para cada catch, es decir el manejo de la excepción estaba duplicado, y la gente tendía a duplicar código en vez de poner un método y llamarlo desde ambos lados.

Para evitar eso se agregó una nueva notación en la que se agregan *pipes* o la barra vertical entre los tipos de excepciones y de esa manera te ahorras escribir dos veces lo mismo quedando:

```
catch (IOException|SQLException ex) {
    logger.log(ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

Esta mejora nos permite reducir lo que se conoce como boilerplate, porque estadísticamente un programador se la pasa leyendo código el 80% de su tiempo, así que entre menos y más conciso mejor.

Tienes dos opciones, cambiar tu multicatch a varios catchs, o ponerle a tu compilador el flag conocido como sourcelevel de esta manera:

```
javac -source 1.8 -target 1.6 MiCodigo.java
```

[como verás](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492948/javac-source-and-target-options) le indicamos que el código está en la nueva forma de digamos java 8, pero que queremos que nos genere un bytecode compatible con una versión anterior como java 6, como si lo hubiéramos generado con una versión anterior pero con la ventaja de tener las vulnerabilidades y bugs corregidos de esa versión.